# How can I SSH from Hong Kong to China?

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

Me in Hong Kong, girl friend in China.

I have installed SSH server on both computers.  When both computers were in Hong Kong, I connected both to the internet (via my internet connection at home), and SSH from BOTH directions works.  This at least indicates that within the 2 computers, the settings and firewalls were OK.

Now that my GF's computer is moved to mainland China, she could still successfully SSH me, but I could no longer SSH her -- connection timeout error.  Even trying to ping her computer (she tells me her IP address via chat) has no response.

How could I resolve this problem?  It is very important that I can SSH her computer to do things on it.

I have told her to connect the PC to the router on the wall, instead of through a Wifi router that she has.

Both PCs are running on Ubuntu linux.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is NOT the setup in your Linux machines, the connection might be blocked by some firewall in the network.

I found this solution ("reverse SSH"), that works by letting your girlfriend SSH to you first and then using THIS connection to ssh back to her:

http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html

The simple setup (where your girlfriend has to do some work each time you want to connect):

```
# first SSH from your girlfriend TO your Laptop
ssh -f -N -R 10000:localhost:22 your_username@ip_address_of_YOUR_laptop

# now ssh to port 10000 on your laptop, which will actually connect you to port 22 on your girlfriend's laptop.
# Use the user information that you would use to log into your girlfriend's computer.
ssh girlfriend_username@localhost -p 10000
```

On the website in the link, there is also a more complete approach, where your girlfriend does not need to interact. But try the simple approach first to see if it works.